# mypy type hinting with an extended pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm learning to use `mypy` and the `pyproject.toml` config

#### `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.mypy]
# Import discovery
files = ["app"]
ignore_missing_imports = true
python_version = "3.10"
platform = "linux-64"
```

#### `app/__main__.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import (
    NamedTuple,
    Generator,
    overload,
    TypeVar,
    Generic,
    Any,
)
import string
import pandas as pd

LETTERS = list(string.ascii_letters)


class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int


KT = TypeVar("KT", str, int, tuple[str, str])
DT = TypeVar("DT", str, int, Point)


class Series(pd.Series, Generic[KT, DT]):
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: KT | int) -> DT:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: list[KT] | list[int] | slice) -> Series[KT, DT]:
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, _: KT | int | list[KT] | list[int] | slice) -> Series[KT, DT]:
        ...

    def __next__(self) -> DT:
        ...

    def __iter__(self) -> Generator[DT, None, None]:
        ...


def make_point_series(data: list[tuple[int, int]]) -> Series[str, Point]:
    return pd.Series((Point(*d) for d in data), index=LETTERS[: len(data)])


def make_point_series_with_tuple_index(
    data: list[tuple[int, int]]
) -> Series[tuple[str, str], Point]:

    index = list(zip(LETTERS[: len(data)], LETTERS[: len(data)]))

    return pd.Series((Point(*d) for d in data), index=index)


DATA = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    points = make_point_series(DATA)  # Series[str,Point]

    a = points["a"]  # Point
    b = points[1]  # Point
    a_b = points[0:1]  # Series[str,Point]

    a_d = points[["a", "d"]]  # Series[str,Point]

    for x in points:
        assert isinstance(x, Point)

    points2 = make_point_series_with_tuple_index(DATA)  # Series[tuple,Point]
    a = points2[("a", "a")]  # Point

    a_b = points2[[("a", "a"), ("b", "b")]]  # Series[tuple,Point]
```

Comment: Are you aware of `pandas-stubs` ?

Comment: I was not.  I will have to investigate.